# Run time Conditional Validation (Required Field) in MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have few Address line fields in my Model class, which changes its behavior (Required / not Required) based on the selected country / language.

For example UK should have 3 address line as Required input field, where as in case of US, it should be only 2 Required fields.

I have tried to use a custom validator "RequiredIf" & turning it on or off based on another **nullable** Boolean property; But its not working.

Concerned property of my Model is mentioed as floows:

```
public bool? IsAddressLine3Mandatory { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("IsAddressline3Mandatory", true, ErrorMessage = "Address line 3 is mandatory for UK")]
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
```

I am fetching the country information from our Database & setting the IsAddressline3Mandatory field in the HTTPGet Action method for that view.

I am trying to achieve both client side & server side validation to happen.

Code for RequiredIf goes as follows:

```
    public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();

    public string DependentProperty { get; set; }
    public object TargetValue { get; set; }

    public RequiredIfAttribute(string dependentProperty, object targetValue)
    {
        this.DependentProperty = dependentProperty;
        this.TargetValue = targetValue;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // get a reference to the property this validation depends upon
        var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
        var field = containerType.GetProperty(this.DependentProperty);

        if (field != null)
        {
            // get the value of the dependent property
            var dependentvalue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            // compare the value against the target value
            if ((dependentvalue == null && this.TargetValue == null) ||
                (dependentvalue != null && dependentvalue.Equals(this.TargetValue)))
            {
                // match => means we should try validating this field
                if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
                    // validation failed - return an error
                    return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage, new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "requiredif",
        };

        string depProp = BuildDependentPropertyId(metadata, context as ViewContext);

        // find the value on the control we depend on;
        // if it's a bool, format it javascript style 
        // (the default is True or False!)
        string targetValue = (this.TargetValue ?? "").ToString();
        if (this.TargetValue.GetType() == typeof(bool))
            targetValue = targetValue.ToLower();

        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("dependentproperty", depProp);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("targetvalue", targetValue);

        yield return rule;
    }

    private string BuildDependentPropertyId(ModelMetadata metadata, ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        // build the ID of the property
        string depProp = viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(this.DependentProperty);
        // unfortunately this will have the name of the current field appended to the beginning,
        // because the TemplateInfo's context has had this fieldname appended to it. Instead, we
        // want to get the context as though it was one level higher (i.e. outside the current property,
        // which is the containing object (our Person), and hence the same level as the dependent property.
        var thisField = metadata.PropertyName + "_";
        if (depProp.StartsWith(thisField))
            // strip it off again
            depProp = depProp.Substring(thisField.Length);
        return depProp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your model? Also how are you toggling the value of the `IsAddressline3Mandatory` property based on the country selection?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : I ve added the concerned model properties. I am fetching the country information from our Database & setting the IsAddressline3Mandatory field in the HTTPGet Action method for that view.

Comment: But the user could change the country in the view, right? How are you updating this property value in this case?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : No, We have not provided this option user. (He cant change the country by his own).